# Get print through 2 tray printer along printing status using PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, printing, hardware-interface

I want to print some text on page with strict position specifications by multi tray printer. Both the printer trays will be used alternatively at run time to print different designs. As I know PHP can not handle it alone, and it need some help of other language which is having system hardware control.

All masters here, would you please help me to solve this problem?
Or can u please give me guidance to do it otherway?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to print to a printer connected to the computer/server PHP is running on, or to a client-side printer at the other end of a browser?

Comment: Sir @deceze, first of all,Thank you. Sir, The clients will be using server to take paper prints.Server and clients will be at different location. All the clients will be using same printer (Lexmark-printer) compulsorily.

Comment: @deceze, Sir waiting for your suggestions, Please...

Comment: I don't have one, I just wanted to clarify the question. :)